# What is the fastest way to connect two machines for a ping-pong test?

Tags: networking, switch, ethernet, nic, infiniband

I need to do a latency test between two machines, basically a ping-pong packet test. I wonder what is the fastest connection I can have between those two machines. I imagine my options are:

1. Ethernet through a router, but then my bottleneck will probably be the router unless you can recommend me a cheap and very fast router
2. Ethernet through a switch, but then my bottleneck will probably be the switch unless you can recommend me a cheap and very fast switch
3. Some kind of NIC-to-NIC connection using an ethernet cable
4. Infiniband (that would be awesome but I don't think I will be able to do that at home due to its cost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At home? [Uhm....](http://serverfault.com/faq)

Do not use extra hardware. No router, no switch. Just connect a Ethernet cable directly between the two NICs. And use the fastest Ethernet to minimise serialisation delays.

The reasons for this:

- Extra hardware can only add delays. Use as few hops as possible.
- It takes time for a datagram to be converter to a set electric signals on the line. Hence the fastest (Ethernet) link you can get.

Comment: You mean use the fastest ethernet card available? What is the fastest one these days?

Comment: The card with the fastest wire speed. Affordable: 1Gbit (next to free). 10Gbit is about EUR 1000. And you would need two of these.

Comment: I am debating if I should do this over loopback and forget about wiretime for now since it will vary over 1Gbit, 10Gbit and Infiniband. Problem is: I will be sharing CPU power with 2 process, and I only have one quad-core chip. Maybe pinning each process to its own core will be enough but not sure.

Answer (score 7):

Connect the two hosts with an Ethernet crossover cable.